# Get property by name

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, reflection

Can i somehow access property by it's name (represented by string) within lambda expression in Linq-to-Sql?

Say, something like

```
collection.Where(x => Get_Property(x, property_name)==property_value)
```

Actually, my problem is a code where `Get_Property` was implemented with reflection so that Linq2Obj was used instead of Linq2Sql and all work was performed by app instead of sql server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [DynamicLINQ](http://nuget.org/packages/DynamicLINQ/). It creates lambda expressions from strings, and those expressions are used by the ORM.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do this, because there is only set of methods which could be converted into SQL. Your custom methods or reflection API is not part of that set.

You can use [Entity SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387145.aspx) to compose your query as a string.